# How should I load the contents of a .txt file to serve on a website?

Tags: linux, apache, sphinx, file-get-contents

I am trying to build excerpts for each document returned as a search results on my website.  I am using the [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) search engine and the Apache web server on Linux CentOS.  The function within the Sphinx API that I'd like to use is called [BuildExcerpts](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.2.html#api-func-buildexcerpts).  This function requires you to pass an array of strings where each string contains the documents contents.

I'm wondering what the best practice is for retrieving the document contents in real time as I serve the results on the web.  Currently, these documents are in text files on my system, spread across multiple drives.  There are roughly 100MM of them and they take up a few terabytes of space.

It's easy for me to call something like `file_get_contents()`, but that feels like the wrong way to do this.  My databases are already gigantic ( 100GB+ ) and I don't particularly want to throw the document contents in there along with the document attributes that already exist.  Perhaps this is the best way to do this, however.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well the source needs to be fetched from somewhere. If you dont want to duplicate it in your database, then you will need to fetch it from the filesystem. (using file_get_contets or similar)

Although the BuildExerpts function does give you one extra option "load_files"

... then sphinx will read the data from the filename for you.

What problem are you experiencing with reading it from files? Is it too slow? If so maybe use some caching in front - using memcache maybe.